# Updating timestamp column based on datefield

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with over 50.000 dates and I need to convert it to a Timestamp field.

Basic table layout:

```
  Fieldname                Type
+------------------------+-----------+
| calendar_date          | DATE      |
| calendar_unixtimestamp | TIMESTAMP |
+------------------------+-----------+
```

so basically:

```
update calender set calendar_unixtimestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(calendar_date)
```

However, wont work, of course. So I've tried another option which was told me on some goofy website, seems logical. However can't get it to work:

```
update
  calendar t1
  join calendar t2 on t2.`calendar_date` = t1.`calendar_date`
set
  t1.calendar_unixtimestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.`calendar_date`)
where
  t1.`calendar_date` = t2.`calendar_date`
```

Anyone?

Comment: why you say it doesn't work? what happens? is calendar_date a date column or a varchar column?

Comment: Ofcourse, sorry. It just won't update anything. Like nothing happened. Ive added table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts, while UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns an unsigned integer.

You should set `calendar_unixtimestamp` to INT.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa5ec2/1).

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin.

I'm not an expert on mysql, but I think you should read this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Especially when it says:

> By default, the first TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is specified explicitly.

The on UPDATE clause causes the field value to change to the current timestamp whenever the record is updated, so you update it, then it is automatically changed to the current timestamp, the same (or almost) for all the records in your table.

Maybe what you need is a DATETIME column. Timestamp columns are intended to register when a record is created and/or updated. This can be useful for many purposes, including security or conflict resolution when multiple users try to update the same record.

a) If this is what you need, you should first disable the ON UPDATE trigger, then make the update (your first one was OK) and then re-create the trigger(*). Just add a WHERE condition to make sure that you don't try to update nulls. Again, I'm not sure that unix_timestamp is the function you need.

```
    
    UPDATE calendar
    SET calendar_timestamp = TIMESTAMP(calendar.date) 
    WHERE calendar_date IS NOT NULL
```

b) If it is not, you simply should change the type of your new column to DATETIME.

(*)Note: Probably it would be easier to drop the column, then create it with the DEFAULT clause but without the ON UPDATE one, or specifying the NULL clause.

Comment: Thanks for the addition mate, however. The point is that im currently running the timestamp output to a jFlot script and that needs timestamp. I dont want every select to have a select unix_timestamp(date) from blabla. Thats the reason why i wanted to update all the collumns. The default value for the timestamp is indeed current_timestamp()

Comment: Well, then you should check if you also have the ON UPDATE trigger. If you have it, you should drop the column, then recreate it with the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() condition but without the ON UPDATE one. Otherwise, you won't be able to update that field. Sorry for all the edits in my post. I'm just new to stackoverflow :)